Cordova iOS and Sencha Ext JS App Misaligned Components and Broken Scrolling After iOS 18.2 Update
After updating my iOS device to version 18.2, my Cordova app (built with Sencha Ext JS) started exhibiting strange behavior:

Components are not rendering in their expected positions.
Scrolling for all components is completely broken.

The app worked perfectly fine on earlier versions of iOS (lower and equal to iOS 18.0), and I haven't made any recent changes to the app's code.
Despite these efforts, the app continues to have misaligned components and broken scrolling functionality on iOS 18.2.

I checked the Cordova iOS repository for any reported issues.
Result: No relevant issues were found.

I came across this article and updated my Sencha Ext JS version to 7.8.
Result: The update did not resolve the issue.

I found reports of similar problems in Flutter, and I suspect the issue might be related to event handling, specifically "coalesced events".

I added Modernizr to my project to test for missing JS features.
Result: No improvement.

I tested the web version of the app directly in Safari on the device.
Result: The same issue occurred, which suggests it’s not just a
Cordova-specific problem.

I removed everything related to WKWebView from the app.
Result: No change.

I added a new webview plugin (cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) to the app.
Result: Still no improvement.


